# Send payload with GET method

Tags: java, http, curl, get, payload

To my knowledge, GET is not supposed to have payload data. However, the Assembla API makes use of GET and data

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-type: application/xml" -d @file.xml https://super:super@www.assembla.com/spaces/:space_id/remove_members
```

When I uses curl in verbose mode, the request is as follow:

```
GET /spaces/ad-redesign-cms/remove_members HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic <some token>
User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.22 librtmp/2.3
Host: www.assembla.com
Accept: application/xml
Content-type: application/xml
Content-Length: 49
```

Is it really that GET can carry data using cURL? If so, how can I make a Java equivalent code?

Comment: GET can carry data, but not in a request body like POST can.  (Basically in the URL)

Comment: as @Sean Reilly pointed out, `-X` allows you to override the command, according to the man page: curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html. deleting my answer.